# NullPointerException while passing context from fragment to SQLiteOpenHelper class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This code runs perfectly in API level 21 but it is not working in API level 19. It is producing a NullPointerException.

I have checked out a lot of problems related to this on Google, but they have not been helpful.

I am calling SQliteOpenHelper from a child fragment, so here is my code with errors:

```
// This is my Chatbox class which a childfragment and
// I am calling this method to pass values in sqlite class

 private void saveConversation(String profile_name,String profile_id,String message,String who){
    sqLite = new SQLite(getContext());
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = sqLite.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLite.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    sqLite.insert(profile_name, profile_id, message, who);
}


//Sqlite class
public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
     SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase  =  this.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues contentValues;
    Context context;

    public static final String DatabaseName = "Communication";
    public static final String TableName1  = "ChatConversation";
    public static final int DatabaseVersion = 2;

    public SQLite(Context context) {
        super(context, DatabaseName, null, DatabaseVersion);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"on create table is called !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TableName1+"(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,profilename VARCHAR(50),profileid VARCHAR(50),message VARCHAR(255),who VARCHAR(20))");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void insert(String profilename,String profileid ,String message, String who){
        Toast.makeText(context,"insert database was called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("profilename",profilename);
        contentValues.put("profileid",profileid);
        contentValues.put("message",message);
        contentValues.put("who",who);
        long id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(SQLite.TableName1,null,contentValues);
        if(id>0){
           Toast.makeText(context,"successfully inserted", LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Something went wrong", LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my error:

```
com.example.shuresnepali.communicationpost, PID: 21374
   java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:117)
   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:275)
   at com.example.shuresnepali.communicationpost.SQLite.onCreate(SQLite.java:28)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
   at com.example.shuresnepali.communicationpost.SQLite.<init>(SQLite.java:13)
   at com.example.shuresnepali.communicationpost.Chat_box.saveConversation(Chat_box.java:283)
   at com.example.shuresnepali.communicationpost.Chat_box.onClick(Chat_box.java:149)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4652)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19318)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is a Null Pointer Exception and how do I fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). By the way, reopening a duplicate is an anti-pattern

Comment: @ModularSynth I reopened since I find closing questions as duplicate to a generic problem-solving approach unhelpful if there is a more specific problem. It's good reference but rarely helps in specific problems.

Comment: Thank you @laalto for helping me out i just pass sqliteDatabase  through the insert method during inserting data in sqlit. thaks again your answer was very supportive

Comment: @laalto EVERY NullPointerException has the SAME origin. Therefore, *seen ONE, seen ALL*. They are ALL fixed by correctly instancing the prematurely referenced object. The duplicate should remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
>       SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase  =  this.getWritableDatabase();
> ```

You're calling `getWritableDatabase()` too early. In Java, member initializers run before constructor body (other than explicit super constructor calls), and you're only initializing `context` in your constructor body. `getWritableDatabase()` in turn calls back to `onCreate()` where you are using the `context` field that is not yet initialized. Further reading: [Java order of Initialization and Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation)

Remove this field, or postpone its initialization to constructor body.

On a related note, you should not call `onCreate()` yourself.

Why it "works" on API 21 and not 19 is likely because on your API 21 device/emulator you already have a database file with the same name, created with an earlier version of your app without this bug. `getWritableDatabase()` only calls back to `onCreate()` if the database file didn't exist. [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Comment: Would you please clear more on this ? i have also heard about this issue but not being able to understand what is going on ??  it would be nice if you help me out ?

Comment: Remove this `getWritableDatabase()` field initializer, and remove the line where you call `onCreate()`. Call `getWritableDatabase()` to init a local var in those methods where you need `SQLiteDatabase()`.

Answer (score 1):

try this use `getActivity()` in fragment to get `Context`

```
private void saveConversation(String profile_name,String profile_id,String message,String who){
        sqLite = new SQLite(getParentFragment().getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = sqLite.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLite.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        sqLite.insert(profile_name, profile_id, message, who);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your quick respond but still no change got the same error as before....i am using childfragment so does it matter ?

Comment: Still didn't work i also tried getParentFragment().getcontex() but still got the same error. it works in api level 21 so would you please consider on that issue ? but not working in api 19 at all.

Comment: @Shures check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297539/how-to-get-the-activity-in-nested-fragments

Answer (score 1):

Use getActivity() for getting Context in fragment;

```
 private void saveConversation(String profile_name,String profile_id,String message,String who){
        sqLite = new SQLite(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = sqLite.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLite.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        sqLite.insert(profile_name, profile_id, message, who);
    }
```

Comment: The Context itself is fine since the NPE is not in `SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help i solve this by ...passing context during insert data, and removed the getwriteabledatabase from initilization

```
 private void saveConversation(String profile_name,String profile_id,String message,String who){
        sqLite = new SQLite(getParentFragment().getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = sqLite.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLite.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        sqLite.insert(profile_name, profile_id, message, who,sqLiteDatabase);
    }
//and after this
 public void insert(String profilename,String profileid ,String message, String who,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        Toast.makeText(context,"insert database was called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("profilename",profilename);
        contentValues.put("profileid",profileid);
        contentValues.put("message",message);
        contentValues.put("who",who);
        long id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(SQLite.TableName1,null,contentValues);
        if(id>0){
           Toast.makeText(context,"successfully inserted", LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Something went wrong", LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```